# DVD/BluRay Drive not showing any disk contents

Tags: mount, dvd

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS server edition on an old gaming rig.

The end goal being to have a headless DVD ripper.

All three drives are visible, and respond to the eject command.

`> ls -ltrFa /dev/sr*
brw-rw---- 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Jan 27 03:18 /dev/sr0
brw-rw---- 1 root cdrom 11, 2 Jan 27 03:18 /dev/sr2
brw-rw---- 1 root cdrom 11, 1 Jan 27 04:00 /dev/sr1`

but for some reason every time I insert any dvd into any of the drives, no data is visible in /mnt/dev/sr[0-2], nor does any of the udev scripts run

The only clue I have so far is this output from dmesg

```
[ 1581.307405] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1581.307409] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#18 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 1581.307412] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#18 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 1581.307416] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#18 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 2e 21 00 00 00 40 00
[ 1581.307417] print_req_error: 1 callbacks suppressed
[ 1581.307419] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 12092416
[ 1581.338235] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#19 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1581.338240] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#19 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 1581.338243] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#19 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 1581.338246] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#19 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 2e 21 00 00 00 02 00
[ 1581.338248] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 12092416
[ 1581.338709] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 1511552, async page read
[ 1584.107616] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#27 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1584.107621] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#27 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 1584.107624] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#27 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 1584.107628] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#27 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 2e 21 00 00 00 40 00
[ 1584.107630] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 12092416
[ 1584.138177] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#28 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1584.138181] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#28 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 1584.138184] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#28 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 1584.138188] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#28 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 2e 21 00 00 00 02 00
[ 1584.138190] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 12092416
[ 1584.138644] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 1511552, async page read
[ 2539.428913] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2539.428918] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#15 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 2539.428921] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#15 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 2539.428925] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#15 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 2e 21 00 00 00 40 00
[ 2539.428928] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 12092416
[ 2539.460964] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2539.460968] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#16 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 2539.460971] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#16 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 2539.460975] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 2e 21 00 00 00 02 00
[ 2539.460977] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 12092416
[ 2539.461438] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 1511552, async page read
[ 2542.257672] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2542.257676] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#24 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 2542.257679] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#24 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 2542.257683] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 2e 21 00 00 00 40 00
[ 2542.257685] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 12092416
[ 2542.296939] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2542.296944] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#25 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 2542.296947] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#25 Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 2542.296950] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr1] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 2e 21 00 00 00 02 00
[ 2542.296952] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr1, sector 12092416
[ 2542.297408] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 1511552, async page read
```

reading some forum posts I tried this (Although I'm not sure how they relate):

```
sudo apt remove       libdvd-pkg  handbrake-cli  
sudo apt install vlc  handbrake-cli libdvd-pkg libdvdcss-dev libdvdcss2 -y
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

This is really quite odd to me

Comment: I see IO errors, or it reads like the disc itself is faulty, or the dvd drive itself is faulty.

Comment: All 3 Drives which are different ages, with IO errors?

Comment: I'm limited to viewing what you have posted; which refers to an IO error on sector 12092416 on dev sr1.  There is no evidence of other drives in your `dmesg` output

Answer (score 1):

I share the same situation but only for some commercial DVDs. The last One I tried to see is APOLLO69 (the story of Apollo 13 with Tom Hanks).
This problem is not drive related. It is an UDEV bug pertaining to the way the UDEV subsystem attempt to decipher/read the DVD and fail. During those attempts the drive gets reset many times, the kernel get stuck into I/O and you finally have to restart the system to square things off.
It seems a bug report has been submitted but closed for old age.
After a huge lot of googling around, I've found a workaround allowing to actually work with the DVD in the drive, even if the DVD icon does not show in the Nautilus file manager.
See this post https://forum.makemkv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25357
Of course, if it is a commercial DVD protected with CSS, you will have to get the keys and tell the drive which keys to use.
If you want to see the files in the DVD, you have to launch VLC or another libcss app aware in order to decipher the disc and then revert to the old fashioned way using sudo mount -o ro /dev/sr0 
I can't create or fill a bug report to the UDEV nor Kernel crew so won't do it but I do hope that this PITA will be solved one day without these strange workaround.
Hope this helps.